# Find lines containing 123985 and Positive_Adjustment in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find lines in files where a specific number AND a specific string occur, with an arbritrary set of characters between them (in other words they each occur anywhere in the line, not next to each other*).

***Edit:**  To clarify,  I am merely stating that the two string values won't be next to each other. I am not saying this is a requirement of the regex.  It will be ok if it finds 123985Positive_Adjustment. It just won't because there are no lines like that.  Apologies if my question was misleading.

I have tried many regular expressions after searching google for this problem but none have done exactly what I need.  One example I've tried is...

`123985.*Positive_Adjustment`

(Search for that number, then an arbritrary number of characters, then that string)

Can anyone suggest a correct regular expression to use that will acheive this in Notepad++ (up-to-date at time of writing)

An example of a valid match would be....

```
15/02/12|abc|123985|G1|6|12:04:29|19088829.96|Positive_Adjustment||||299243.70|||0.00|299243.70|15/02/12|||10.9.210.0||5001|0.0000|||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Comment: What do you mean by not next to each other?

Comment: I just mean that there will be other characters between them on the line,  so they will not be right next to each other like this "123985Positive_Adjustment"

Comment: post some examples for valid and invalid matches.

Comment: `^.*123985.+Positive_Adjustment.*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in other words they each occur anywhere in the line, not next to each other

```
^.*123985.+Positive_Adjustment.*$
```

This simple regex should do it for you.

Comment: It's not working, but maybe I am doing something wrong.  I will keep trying.

Comment: @MrVimes in ur exmaple you have `Pos_Adjustment` and in your requirement you have `Positive_Adjustment` ?????/

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.

Comment: It did work eventually.  I must have typed it incorrectly.  Thankyou.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify that 'not next to each other' wasn't a requirement, merely a statement of fact about the actual data being searched through.  It would be ok if it found those strings touching, but it just wouldn't because there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

You can describe parts that are not the number or the word you search. The result is a bit long but efficient (because it quickly fails):

```
^(?:[^1\n]+|1(?!23985))*+123985(?:[^P\n]+|P(?!ositive_Adjustment))++Positive_Adjustment.*
```

or more long and more fast:

```
^[^1\n]*+(?:1(?!23985)[^1\n]*)*+123985(?>[^P\n]+|P(?!ositive_Adjustment)[^P\n]*)(?:P(?!ositive_Adjustment)[^P\n]*)*+Positive_Adjustment.*
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564845/find-lines-containing-123985-and-positive-adjustment-in-notepad?noredirect=1#comment45440235_28564845) comment.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I have seen it, and it fails when there are no characters between them. It isn't what he asked?